# VS 2022 .NET 6.0 "Always start when Debugging"

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0

I have an netstandard2.1 Project in my Solution that always starts even when I start debugging another project. I can enable this in Properties in the Solution explorer.

[image]

Now I added a .NET 6.0 project to the solution and I want the same behaviour. But I don't know where to enable this feature.

[image]

How can I activate the feature?

Comment: Maybe you have opened the wrong properties window? If I open any runable api or app project (net5, 6, ...) I have the view of your first picture. In all netstandard projects I have your second picture, because netstandard projects are not able to be runable without a runtime project itself.

Comment: @Martin do you have any Idea how I could get to that property window? This property window comes along when I click the project in the solution. I don't know how else I can get to that.

Comment: I am looking for this too and it appears to have been removed - at least from the project properties window where it used to be. for a new .net core project there are simply no properties there at all. great job microsluff

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for VS feature [multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2022#start-debugging-with-multiple-processes).

To select multiple projects as  startup you can right-click on the solution item in the solution explorer, select "Properties" and then under "Common Properties" -> "Startup Project" click on "Multiple startup projects" and select needed ones:

[image]

Comment: this is not the answer I was looking for but this basically solves my problem